# Laravel 5.1: Changing PHP version used by Artisan Facade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have an application that will run an Artisan command via a controller:

```
Artisan::call('myCommand');
```

The problem is that my production server doesn't have their Terminal PHP version up to speed, so they needed to put in a fix for my running of composer and artisan commands ( I now use /usr/bin/php55 ).

Now, when I try to to call the Artisan command via my controller, I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in on line 54
```

This error is due to the PHP version being wrong, which agrees with previous issues I have had on my production server.

Does anyone know how I can change the version of PHP used by the Artisan Facade? Preferably without changing any core Laravel code :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a command via **Artisan::call()** you are not creating a separate process. The command code is executed with the same process that handles the request and uses the same PHP version. There is no way to make it use another PHP version when calling it via **Artisan** facade.

In order to use different PHP version you need to run the command in a separate process. You can use Symfony's **Process** class for that - it's bundled with Laravel, so there is no need to install anything.

This should work for you:

```
$process = new Process('/usr/bin/php55 artisan command:name');
$process->run();
```

Comment: I think that will fix the original issue, but I have discovered other issues throughout the code - I guess I need to try and get my server php updated to >=5.5, or I'm going to be sticking fixes in all over the place. Thanks anyway :)